# How to check date of birth is keyed in

Tags: php, html

i would like to know how to check if user has entered their date of birth in the registration form. The day and month are in a drop down list and the year is in text box form.

```
<b>Date of birth</b>
<select name="day" id="dobday">
<option value="na">Day</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="11">11</option>
<option value="12">12</option>
<option value="13">13</option>
<option value="14">14</option>
<option value="15">15</option>
<option value="16">16</option>
<option value="17">17</option>
<option value="18">18</option>
<option value="19">19</option>
<option value="20">20</option>
<option value="21">21</option>
<option value="22">22</option>
<option value="23">23</option>
<option value="24">24</option>
<option value="25">25</option>
<option value="26">26</option>
<option value="27">27</option>
<option value="28">28</option>
<option value="29">29</option>
<option value="30">30</option>
<option value="31">31</option>
</select> 

<select name="dobmonth" id="dobmonth">
<option value="na">Month</option>
<option value="January">January</option>
<option value="February">February</option>
<option value="March">March</option>
<option value="April">April</option>
<option value="May">May</option>
<option value="June">June</option>
<option value="July">July</option>
<option value="August">August</option>
<option value="September">September</option>
<option value="October">October</option>
<option value="November">November</option>
<option value="December">December</option>
</select>`

<input type="text" name="dobyear" title="dobyear" style="color:#888;"
value="year" onfocus="inputFocus(this)" onblur="inputBlur(this)" />
```

I would also like to input the function when user click on certain month, the date checks accordingly . Like the 30 , 31 and ,28 on certain months (: 
Only using html or php.

Comment: So you're expecting someone else to do all the server side coding for you?

Comment: @EternalHour If your not going to help then dont comment.

Comment: @bubblebee if you're not willing to put in some effort don't ask questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use HTML5's `required` attribute:

```
<input type=text required/>

<select required></select>
```

Although it's not fully supported by some older browsers

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/L2mg0kc1/)

**UPDATE**

You need to add `required` and for `select`s you need to set the first `option` to a blank value like so:

```
<option value="">Month</option>
```

[**NEW FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/L2mg0kc1/2/)

Comment: is this only for textbox ? or does it works with drop down list ? (:

Comment: @bubblebee the select example I added is for dropdowns. I included a fiddle too

Comment: It didnt work in my codes, not sure if i used it wrongly but are you Able to help me using my codes? thank you very much (:

Comment: what browser are you using?

Comment: did you try clicking submit in the fiddle i added to my answer?

Comment: Yes i did. it worked, but not on my codes

Comment: can you post a link to your code? or try and recreate it in a fiddle?

Comment: here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/L2mg0kc1/1/

Comment: You got it. Glad to help

Answer (score 1):

Use Jquery to change the date according dropdowns on change of month.

myjsonarray is array as following,

```
{ "january":{"1","2","3" .... "31"}, "February":{"1","2"..."29"}, ... }
```

According to the months ...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

            prevhtml = jQuery("#dobday").html();
        });

                function changedays(){

                    var selected = jQuery("#dobmonth option:selected").text();




                if(myjsonarray[selected]){
                    jQuery.each(myjsonarray[selected], function( index, value ) {

                        html +="<option value=\""+index+"\">"+value+"</option>"; 
                    });
                }

                if(!myjsonarray[selected]) html=prevhtml;
                jQuery("#dobday").html(html);

                }
```

Also change your select statement as

```
<select name="dobmonth" id="dobmonth" on-change="changedays()">
```